# onclick jquery not working after ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net

I am completely new to jQuery.

I have written an onclick event like this:

```
     $(document).ready(function () {
         $('body').find('.milestonetable').each(function () {
            var mTable = $(this);
            $(this).find('tr:first').children().eq(0).find('table').find('tr:last').children().eq(0).find('span').on('click', function () {
                var _mid = $(mTable).parent().next('table').find('tbody').find('tr').children().eq(1).find('input').val();
             //some other things to do.
            });

         });
    });
```

Its working fine.
But when I call an ajax, it stops working.
I have figured out that I have to write it something like this:

```
      $(document).on('click','.someclassName', function () {  

       });
```

But I am unable to convert the above code similar to the code below. 
Kindly help.

Note: I am using jQuery 1.10.4

Comment: Read about event delegation http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Comment: The delegated form of `on` is exactly what you should use. We can't really help you any further than that with the lack of information you've provided.

Comment: give us the code where u made the Ajax call

Comment: whan you say call an ajax - is that an asp.net ajax postback ?

Comment: @Mahatma Aladdin, I posted the main idea for you to follow. If need more assistance please share your html and more details.

Answer (score 4):

Configuring the event in the following way might overcome your issue.

```
$(document).on("click",".class-added-to-your-span", function(){


});
```

More details on the live delegation can be found here > 
http://api.jquery.com/live/

Answer (score 0):

You may replace your code to this code:

```
$('.milestonetable').on('click', '.class-added-to-your-span', function () {
    var mTable = $(this).closest('.milestonetable');


});
```

Note that I added a class to the span you are searching for: `class-added-to-your-span`

This way you attach the click event handler to the `.milestonetable` for your span, and get your code a bit simpler.

Comment: Can you describe a little better what this does rather then just posting code.